# Share image using url in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, share

I want to share an image dynamically taking a URL and then sharing it as it works in easy_flutter_share.
but I am not able to do it in flutter share: ^2.0.1 package.
will you please provide a code example for this use case?

like below I uses easy_flutter_share but not able to implement it on share: ^2.0.1 package:

```
var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(imgUrl));

var response = await request.close();
Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
await Share.file(
    'ESYS AMLOG',
    'amlog.jpg',
    bytes,
    'image/jpg',
    text: "download now",
);
```